# Using solar with a 3 phase motor to generate stable 3 phase current

Tags: solar-cell, inverter, generator

I have a 220 V 100 hp electrical motor.

I initially had a plan to use the grid 110 V through a step up transformer to get to 220 V along with a 480 kVA capacitors to kick start the 3 phase 100 hp motor. This would power all the smaller equipment but mostly a 50 hp motor for pumping.

I no longer have access to the 110 V grid system. Let's say that I have a suitably large battery bank with 480 kVA capacitors in parallel.

Would I be able to use an inverter from the battery/capacitor bank to still kick start the motor and generate stable 3 phase power?

solar -> mppt -> [_x battery bank] + [13 480 kVA capacitors] plus  inverter to run the 100 hp motor?

Comment: Are you saying that you are going to drive the motor with the inverter and at the same time use it as a generator to power the smaller equipment and a 50 HP (37.5 kW) pump? Or are you trying to **mechanically** drive the pump using this motor via drive belts or similar? This seems most unlikely.

Comment: Assuming that you have 50kW+ of solar available, you should just get an inverter that'll supply you with 50kW of three phase at a suitable voltage.

Comment: @Transistor I wanted to use the solar to drive 100hp to generate stable 3 phase

Comment: @TimWescott I have over 200 310volt panels so the wattage shouldn't be an issue. I wasn't sure if I could get both single phase 110v for normal equipment and 3 phase 220v for the more heavy duty equipment. Are there inverters like that?

Comment: So you are trying to make a setup to use the motor as a motor and as a generator?

Comment: @Transistor It's a rotary phase converter, using the larger motor 3 phase 100hp to drive the smaller 3 phase 50hp pump as well as some smaller 3 phase tools.

Comment: Sounds XY problem to me. What is you end goal? Please draw a block diagram.

Comment: @winny The end goal is to have stable 3 phase power for multiple machines that needs it. The issue with VFD will be; machines with multiple motors or multiple machines. The main issue is would solar be able to power a rotary phase converter

Comment: Sure, but why would you go to the extreme trouble of rotating machine conversion instead of just an inverter and a VFD for each machine?

Comment: @winny 1 rotating motor can power multiple 3 phase machines or 1 machine with different motors vs multiple VFD for each machine.

Comment: I still fail to see how it would be worth the effort given the price of a VFD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For powering 3-phase motors, it is probably best to use motor-control inverters, also known as variable frequency drives (VFDs). They can start the motors with no or very little extra current required during starting. You should be able to find VFDs that will accept 300 V dc input.

It sounds like you may have been planning to use the 100 Hp motor as part of a phase converter setup. You wouldn't need that, but you would need a VFD for each 3-phase motor. It is possible to use one VFD for more than one motor if the motors would always be running at the same time. If only one motor is running and you need to add another, you would need to stop the first motor, connect the second and restart both.

Comment: Yes and 100 Hp VFD’s are about $4k http://www.gohz.com/100hp-vfd or get smaller ones for each task.   But then what to do with the idle 100Hp motor (hmm)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use mppt vfd unit for 50hp motor. This also eliminates need for rotary converter with capacitors. Be carefull, do NOT connect capacitors across VFD output, beacouse most VFD have a PWM output, saving on output filter. Btw all the smaller eqipment will have to be powered separatelly( anouther part of solar panels -> mppt charger -> battery bank -> inverter -> ( maybe transfor for 110 /220) -> loads.